# В чем может быть ошибка указания пути передачи файла?

Tags: windows, winapi, c++

```
while (true)
{
    cout << ("Отправить файл? (Enter - да, ESC - выход): \n");

    int ch = getch();

    if (ch == VK_ESCAPE) break;
    else if (ch == VK_RETURN)
    {
        HANDLE file = CreateFile("input.txt",      
            GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

        DWORD size = GetFileSize(file, NULL);
        CloseHandle(file);

        ifstream fin("input.txt", ios::binary);
```

Comment: у меня Visual подчеркивает красным  "input.txt"

Comment: с++

Comment: Я перенес  *.сpp в другой solution и программа перестала работать :-(

Comment: скорее всего это настройки… вот только какие?

Comment: Посмотрите настройку в разных проектах - 
Project -> properties -> Configuration Properties -> Character Set.

Они должны быть одинаковыми.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вводите вариант TEXT("input.txt")

Comment: так я уже пробовал и не работает :-(

Comment: Не работает - что пишет?

Comment: andruxa, спасибо! помогло!

Comment: я про настройки

Answer (score 0):

Если в последней строке вы создаёте новый объект ifstream,

```
ifstream fin = new ifstream("input.txt", ios::binary);
```

Comment: у меня только первый “input.txt” подчеркнут где “CreateFile("input.txt",  ”